# How to Silently Install SQL Server 2008 Express In InstallShield 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, installshield-2010, redistributable, silent-installer

I use InstallShield 2010 to create my setup.

My program needs SQL Server 2008 Express. So I added "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 (x86)" in the redistributables section.

Then in "Edit Prerequisites" => "Application To Run" tab, I insert this statement in a textbox:

```
SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER 
       /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="YesYes"  
       /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" 
       /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true
```

http://i46.tinypic.com/a0a343.jpg

But when I run the setup, after some minutes I see this message and SQL Server 2008 Express isn't installed.

http://i50.tinypic.com/2krcr9.jpg

Now how can I completely install SQL Server 2008 Express in silent mode?

**[UPDATE]**

***Problem Solved:***

I Do 3 Steps To Solved My Problem:

1- Restart My Computer

2- Delete "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true" From Statement

3 - Delete /SQLSVCPASSWORD="YesYes" From Statement

Comment: What happens if you run this command line statement manually, on a command prompt? Also: are you **sure** there isn't already an instance of name `MSSQLSERVER` (that's the default name for an instance) on that target machine?

Comment: Hi Mehdi, please add your solution as answer and remove it from the question.

Comment: I have the same problem could you please take a look at my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483104/sql-server-2012-doesnt-install-silently-in-install-shield-11-4-1

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure **/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS** requires a boolean value at all?... I just include the statement, without a parameter value and it works.

Comment: Sorry - this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It should not have a boolean value. It stands by itself.

Answer (score 2):

After several hour trying,I have done it:

1.In InstallShield2010,Go to:"Installation Designer" Tab->Application Data->Redistributable

2.Find the “Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 (x86 & x64Wow)” from the list and right click on it and click on "Edit Prerequisite" .

3.In “Application to Run” write:

/qs /INSTANCEID=”SQLEXPRESS” /ACTION=”Install” /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=”SQLEXPRESS” /SQLSVCACCOUNT=”NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM” /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”Builtin\Administrators” /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN

in “Specify command line for the application”.

For more information,Please take a look at:
http://www.hadirobati.com/wpEn/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008-express-in-installshield/

Comment: Hi Hadi, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Hadi Robati see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838756/send-byte-array-on-serial-port-out-put-stream/