# SQL Server 2012 doesn't install silently in Advanced Installer 11.4.1

Tags: installation, sql-server-express, silent-installer, advanced-installer

My program needs SQL Server 2012 Express. So I added "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express" in feature-based as you can see here :

[image]

I need to install the SQL Server Express in the background without any wizard installation so I added these parameters to my setup file :

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLENGINE 
      /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"      
      /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators"     
      /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"
```

I added these parameters to install command lines textboxes. As you can see here:

[image]

But when I build the project and install the setup file, SQL Server Express doesn't get installed - why?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install SQL Server as a feature-based prerequisite because of the changes its own installer does on the machine. In the online user guide from Advanced Installer you can find a guide on other [options to install SQL Server Express with your application](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html)