# Send byte array on serial port out put stream

Tags: java, android, serial-port

when I want to send byte array on serial port stream with java,on destination device I receive different result !!!

```
byte[] sendingPack = new byte[7];
    sendingPack[0] = 0x6E;
    sendingPack[1] = 0x55;
    sendingPack[2] = (byte) 0x0D;
    sendingPack[3] = (byte) (1 & 0x000000FF);
    sendingPack[4] = 0x01;
    sendingPack[5] = 0x0D; 
    sendingPack[6] = (byte) 0xAA;

    getSendBuffer().getOutputStream().write(sendingPack);

sending array : byte[]{0x6E,0x55,0x0D,0x01,0x01,0x0D,0xAA} 
receive result array : 6E 55 0D 0A 01 01 0D 0A AA
```

on CodeVisionAVR terminal I receive "0A"!!
how can I solve this problem??

Comment: @Indeed same as this 110 85 13 10 1 1 13 10 -86

Comment: @greenapps I can't sent hexadecimal in out put stream

Comment: @greenapps actuly I put all in hexadecimal ,after device send result changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100890/discussion-between-saeed-hashemi-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps I send 6E 55 0D 01 01 0D AA and result 6E 55 0D 0A 01 01 0D 0A AA

Comment: Who is at the receiving side? How does it read the bytes? Give more info in your post.

Comment: @greenapps whit terminal on CodeVisionAVR

Comment: `have 0A plussage`. Please describe what happens better. You let us debug too much. You could much better tell what happens and where.

Comment: @greenapps when I send 6E 55 0D 01 01 0D AA ,must I receive 6E 55 0D 01 01 0D AA and not 6E 55 0D 0A 01 01 0D 0A AA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal is probably in text reading mode and not in binary read mode.

The 0x0A which is inserted after every 0x0D you send is a carriage return conversion.

The terminal converts "\r" to "\r\n". It adds a line feed char to every carriage return.

The terminal converts every 0D to 0D 0A.

This same `feature` can be found in the ftp protocol. You tell your client how to transfer files: in text or binary mode.